# Post request on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I tried to make a request on a webserver with my windows phone, but I doesn't work.

I have this code that works on my computer

```
var client = new WebClient
        {
            BaseAddress = "https://xxx.xxx-xxx.com/"
        };

        var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"wrap_name", userName},
            {"wrap_password", password},
            {"wrap_scope", scope}
        };

        // WebClient takes care of URL Encoding
        var responseBytes = client.UploadValues("issue/wrap", "POST", values);
```

I know that client.UploadValues is not available on windows phone. So I made this code on my wp

```
            var email = "xxx@xxx.org";
            var password = "xxx";
            var data = "wrap_name=" + email + "&wrap_password=" + password + "&wrap_scope=http://xxx.com/";
            var url = "https://xxx.xxx-xxx.com/issue/wrap";

                            var wc = new WebClient { 
                //BaseAddress = "https://login.solar-inverter.com/"
            };
            var URI = new Uri(url);
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc__UploadStringCompleted);

            wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", data);
```

I use fiddler and I got this
[image: Image from fiddler]

Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think 13001 is the request you are looking for.  Also, why are you using BaseAddress and the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

I have to check all the response header. So I see that the accept encoding was at "identity". I have the change it to "*".

Here is the link that explain how it works http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

And in my case the response was in gzip. I use SharpGis as the webclient. Here is the nuget path https://nuget.org/packages/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient
And with SharpGIS you don't need anymore to set the header

Comment: You can also have a look now at the new portable httpclient released 2 weeks ago, and the portable compression support (released last week) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/29/get-httpclient-rtm-200-ok.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/06/06/portable-compression-and-httpclient-working-together.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You should URLEncode the email and password field before adding them to the post body string.
2. You should add a `Content-Type` request header with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

You can use Fiddler's Compare Sessions feature to compare the working and non-working request and adjust the non-working request to exactly match the working request.

Comment: I edited the code. And it still not working. I got the same result as before.